# How can I set x-access-token for NSURLRequest?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest

How can I set x-access-token for NSURLRequest?
Here is what I have now:

```
var url = NSURL(string:"url")!

let authorization = "Bearer \(toke)"

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.addValue("Bearer \(toke)", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Auth-Token")
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution:

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
    "X-MYAPI-Key" : "sdSDfgsdfjdsf3rsdfSDqy3y"]
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration)

let urlString = "https://api.myapiservice.com"
guard let url = NSURL(string: urlString) else { return }
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) {
   (data, response, error) in
}
task.resume()
```